# Connecting iPad to Mac Mini for Xcode development

Tags: ios, xcode, connection, device

I can't seem to get any recognition between the iPad and the Mac Mini. I'm using the white USB cable that came with the iPad to connect them. Tried rebooting ad nauseum. It's like two inert bodies, no indication on either side that the two are connected. No lights, sounds or animations. All the tutorials say is just connect them, and don't mention about what to do if this elementary step fails. I saw some similar questions on other forums, but distressingly, they go unanswered. Any help would be appreciated! Yimin

Comment: Have you checked to see if iTunes recognizes your iPad?

Comment: Have you tried a different cable and/or a different port?

Comment: If you're plugging the cord directly into the ipad and directly into a USB port on your computer (no middle-man devices in the process) then it sounds like the cord just doesn't work.  Try taking it to an Apple store and getting them to swap it for you.

Comment: @WrightsCS - How do I do that? (i.e. check if iTunes recognizes the iPad)

Comment: @WendiKidd - The cable still works to charge the device, but I can bring it back to see if maybe it's not working.

Comment: @NathanRunge does you iPad show up in iTunes, like to where you can sync, backup, etc.?

Comment: I understood that it wasn't working at all.  If it works to charge, the cord isn't the problem.

Comment: @WrightCS - Once I opened iTunes, it recognized the device and the rest was easy. That step "Setup the device in iTunes first." should be included in the tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device needs to be set up in iTunes first. This step is appears to be omitted from many tutorials or perhaps it is a new feature and the tutorials are out of date.

In any case, it would be helpful if there were some kind of visual confirmation when a new device is connected and maybe a suggestion on what to do next.

On the other hand, setting up the provisioning profile in Xcode seems to be greatly simplified now. No need to copy the ID, run the key generator, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode, you need to go to **Organizer** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. On the left sidebar, choose the iPad you want to use for development, for example:

[image]

Alternatively, you can try and kill **iTunes Helper** in from Activity Monitor and then relaunch iTunes.

If all else fails, try another USB port or try another USB cable.

Comment: I see the Mac Mini itself (?) and "Provisioning Profiles". Doesn't look anything like what you have.

Comment: That screenshot was old, I've updated with a current one. So try killing **iTunes Helper** (and restart iTunes), If that does nothing for you, then try a new USB cable. If THAT fails, then I would assume the USB port is malfunctioning.